# serving multiple bots from one bot instance

Tags: asp.net-web-api, botframework

I want to serve multiple bots from one bot instance. 
For example : api/bot1/messages, api/bot2/messages, etc.
I google that and i found some dead links from github.

I read in documentation : https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/connectormisc.html#securing

But how to setup this ? Do i need some routing configuration in my web api ?

How to "load" right microsoft app id and password to messages controller ?

Btw i'm new in web api and bot framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new bot in C#, you're getting a MessagesController with the Default route api/Messages.

To create a second Bot within the same Project, you can create a new Controller (e.g. copy the MessagesController and rename it). Then you get a new route with the Name of the Controller, for example SecondMessagesController => api/SecondMessages

With the `RoutePrefix` Attribute above the Class Definition you can change the route name, for example `[RoutePrefix("api/bot1messages")]`.

That's, what I've tested localy without any problem. The following Part is needed to publish the bot, but I didn't tested that yet:

Currently, both Bots have the same authorization, because both are using the `web.config` to get AppId and AppPassword. But the BotFrameworks Needs individual Id and Password for each Bot. To get that, you can provide them directly inside the `BotAuthorization` Attribute, for example `[BotAutorization(AppId = "MyId", AppPassword = "MyPassword")]`

Comment: It throws an error. Exception is 400 (there is more than one messages controller). I didn't understand this quite well because the routes are different.

Comment: Can you send more Details about the exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488700/bot-does-not-respond-to-messages